# Bug in Perforce 'p4 integrate' Argument Ordering

Tags: perforce

I ran into a weird situation today using the `p4` linux client. I wonder if anyone has seen this or can explain why it happens:

```
$ p4 integrate -b dev -v -i -t -Ds -Dt @34864
//depot/dev/.../TestBo.java - can't branch from //depot/main/.../TestBo.java#4 without -d or -Dt flag

$ p4 integrate -b dev -v -i -t -Dt -Ds @34864
//depot/dev/.../TestBo.java#3 - branch from //depot/main/.../TestBo.java#4
```

Notice that `-Dt` and `-Ds` argument were reversed.

```
$ p4 info
Server version: P4D/NTX64/2009.2/273932 (2010/11/16)
```

Comment: Worth a call to Perforce support to see if it's a reported bug.  It might be fixed in a later version - 2009.2 is a few years old now.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing no mention of this behavior [here](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/integrate.html) and that you're running a `2009.2` build when `2012.2` is available, I'd suggest upgrading if at all possible or maybe contact their support directly.

Comment: I'm upgrading this weekend, if I can reproduce the issue after that I'll let you know.

Comment: Excellent, I'm not sure how fast their web support is but last time I wrote to them on twitter the answer was almost instant!